# QTableView отображение изображения

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, listview, tableview

Допустим есть класс Book. В нем хранится описание книги и QImage. Как мне переопределить методы QAbstractTableModel чтобы в первом столбце выводилось это изображение, а во втором - текст. 
Не проще ли будет использовать QAbstrctListModel и в нем изменить ItemDelegate. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простой вариант - использовать роль [Qt::DecorationRole](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) при формировании значения ячейки в функции `QAbstractItemModel::data`. С помощью этой роли можно выводить в ячейке `QImage` (еще можно `QIcon` или `QPixmap`) без использования специальных делегатов.

Конкретно вывод картинок, при обработке роли `Qt::DecorationRole`, выполняет стандартный [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html), этот делегат работает по умолчанию в представлениях. Либо проследите, что делегат, который вы используете, корректно обрабатывает роль `Qt::DecorationRole`. Так например, другой стандартный делегат [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html), будет выводить только `QIcon` или `QPixmap`, а `QImage` не будет.